# && и || и их братья & и | в разных ситуациях. Какие у них различия?

Tags: java, логические-выражения

друзья! Хотелось бы спросить про && и ||.
Если используется двойной амперсанд и первое выражение ложно (false), то второе выражение даже не будет проверяться, т.к. вне зависимости от него,всё выражение будет ложным. При одном амперсанде будут вычислены оба условия.

Всё понятно, но есть ли смысл иметь в ЯП двойной амперсанд?
Посмотрел, поиспользовал,честно не понял зачем их 2 придумали. Все мои результаты как только не делал вышли одинаковыми.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;
        int c = 4;

        if (a == 2 && b == 3){
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }else{
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
}
```

Да я понимаю, что с && он проверяет первое значение и если оно false, то дальше даже не проверяет, тогда вопрос: Нужен ли в таком случае &(одинарный амперсанд)?
Распишите примеры пожалуйста, где идут отличия & от && и где они могут по разному работать, потому что я увидел только одинаковую работу.

Comment: Функция помимо возвращения логического значения может ещё иметь некие побочные эффекты. Хотя, конечно, лучше так не писать.

Comment: Я написал просто пример, что допустим с & и с && будет одинаковый ответ, заранее  :)

Comment: Как я понял из трёх одинаковых ответов, двухсимвольные операторы  нужны для правильных сравнений, а короткие для сомнительного кода, от которого вреда больше чем пользы. И читаться односимвольные должны так: "смотри, читатель! Тут нам мало получить результат сравнения, на самом деле писатель заложил какой-то сюрприз где-то там в глубине" ...

Comment: Великолепный комментарий))

Comment: `&`, `|` побитовая проверка, `&&`, `||` логические операторы. не знаю, о как "сомнительном коде" идет речь. мат.логика в помощь.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Операторы `|` и `||` - это логические операторы `ИЛИ`. Работает так: если хотя бы одно условие `true`, то все результат true. Т.е., если одно условие `false`, а другое - `true`, то результат true.
- Операторы `&` и `&&` - это логические операторы `И`. Работает так: если хотя бы одно условие `false`, то результат - `false`. Т.е, чтобы результат был `true`, надо чтобы оба условия были `true`.

Допустим, у вас такая проверка: `checkFirst() && checkSecond()`.

`boolean` метод `checkSecond()`:

```
...
System.out.println("Метод checkSecond был вызван т.к. метод checkFirst вернул true");
...
```

И эта надпись может выводиться в консоль, а может и не выводиться. А если бы вы указали `&`, то она бы выводилась всегда, даже если бы `checkFirst` возвращал `false`. Т.е. иногда надо, чтобы проверялись оба условия, независимо от того, повлияет ли это на что-нибудь. А `&&` было придумано для улучшения производительности, мало ли какие громоздкие проверки у вас стоят - чтобы они не выполнялись лишний раз.

P.S. [Andrey NOP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-nop) написал в комментариях к вопросу про побочные эффекты, `println` выше - это как раз побочный эффект. Вместо `println` может быть присваивание какого-то значения важному полю, и т.п.

**UPD:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //тут вызовутся оба метода, т.к. checkFirst возвр. true, потом вызовется checkSecond, он тоже true, условие выполнится
    if (checkFirst(0) && checkSecond(0))
        System.out.println("Первое условие выполнено\n");

    //тут вызовется только checkFirst, т.к. checkFirst возвр. false, и уже не надо проверять checkSecond, т.к. условие ложное, оно не выполнится
    if (checkFirst(1) && checkSecond(0))
        System.out.println("Второе условие выполнено\n");

    //здесь вызовутся оба метода, т.к. это "&", и оба вернут true, условие выполнится
    if (checkFirst(0) & checkSecond(0)) 
        System.out.println("Третье условие выполнено\n");

    //здесь вызовутся оба метода, условие не выполнится, т.к. checkSecond возвр. false
    if (checkFirst(0) & checkSecond(1)) 
        System.out.println("Четвертое условие выполнено\n");
}

private static boolean checkFirst(int i) {
    System.out.println("Вызван checkFirst");
    if (i == 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}

private static boolean checkSecond(int i) {
    System.out.println("Вызван checkSecond");
    if (i == 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Вызван checkFirst
Вызван checkSecond
Первое условие выполнено

Вызван checkFirst

Вызван checkFirst
Вызван checkSecond
Третье условие выполнено

Вызван checkFirst
Вызван checkSecond
```

Comment: А что нам тогда мешает сделать checkFirst() || checkSecond() // если там по факту 1 значение истинное нам нужно? Или мы ставим такое условие & чтобы если и то и то сработало, чтобы оно выдало нам правильное(ые) значение(я)

Comment: Почему одно истинное? Там как раз если первый метод возвр. `false`, то второй метод не будет вызываться, а если первый метод возвр. `true`, то второй вызовется, и выведется надпись.

Comment: @ПетровИван Т.е., если первый возвр. true, то вызовутся оба метода.

Comment: Можете расписать весь код, чтобы посмотрел наглядно, а так я вроде понял, что вы написали. Просто хочу полностью увидеть код, чтобы потом покапаться в нём, заранее благодарю

Comment: а если первый метод возвр. true, то второй вызовется, и выведется надпись. (но второй если будет false) он же не выведет ничего

Comment: @Regent исправил

Comment: @Regent странно, 5 человек плюсы поставили, и никто не заметил

Comment: Пятый плюс от меня - можно считать, что на нём и заметили) А вообще - при простом чтении ответа этих ошибок не видно. Я просто внимательно редактировал ответ - потому и заметил

Answer (score 13):

Простейший пример. Допустим, есть массив размером 10:

```
if(i < 10 && a[i] == 0) { ... }

if(i < 10 & a[i] == 0) { ... }
```

При `i >= 10` во втором случае (`&`) при проверке условия будет попытка обращения к элементу за границами массива, в первом случае (`&&`) все отработает корректно (правая часть условия не будет проверяться, т.к. левая часть условия ложная).

Answer (score 7):

В некоторых случаях требуется вычислять оба операнда логического оператора, чтобы проявились побочные эффекты:

```
class SideEffects {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i = 0;
    /*Значение переменной i инкрементируется, несмотря на то что проверяемое условие в операторе if ложно */
    if(false & (++i < 100)) System.out.println("Эта строка не будет отображаться");
    System.out.println("Оператор if выполняется: " + i); // отображается 1
    
    /* В данном случае значение переменной i не инкрементируется, т.к. второй операнд укороченного логического оператора не вычисляется,а значит, инкремент пропускается */
    if(false && (++i < 100)) System.out.println("Эта строка не будет отображаться");
    System.out.println("Оператор if выполняется: " + i); //по-прежнему отображается 1 !!
    }
}
```

Если логика программы требует, чтобы второй операнд логического оператора
непременно вычислялся, следует применять обычные, а не укороченные формы
логических операций.

Источник: Герберт Шилдт. Java 8.Руководство для начинающих, с.78

Comment: второй операнд укороченного логического оператора не вычисляется.он получается не вычисляется, но все равно в & примере в sout выводит 1, а во втором примере && не вычисляется, вы не спутали? или я запутался?

Comment: @ПетровИван, во втором if выводится единица, вычисленная в первом if

Comment: Ааа допер, спасибо

Answer (score -3):

если в бинар файле ,  за картинкой идет еще картинка . То  && найдет заголовок только верхней первой картинки ffd8ffe0,
и если встречает ffd9ffd8ffe0 то игнорирует ffd8ffe0 ,в итоге нижн картинку пропускает. а & найдет все картинки

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]