# оператор && не работает в цикле while

Tags: java, while

Почему цикл while выходит из цикла при достижении условия (b++ < 5)), а не при достижении (a++ < 10))?

```
package WhileLoop;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;

        while ((a++ < 10) && (b++ < 5)) {
            c++;
        }
        System.out.println(c + ", " + a + ", " + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если ответ решил ваш вопрос, примите его, нажав на стрелку вверх и галочку рядом с ним

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/894602/и-и-их-братья-и-в-разных-ситуациях-Какие-у-них-различия

Answer (score 2):

Здесь работает логический оператор && (условное И), который означает, что общее условие (в д.случае это условие цикла while) срабатывает (т.е. true), когда все булевы выражения истинны. Т.е. оба условия в скобках должны быть истинны (true), в данном примере это работает до момента, когда "a" и "b" достигают значения 5. При дальнейшем увеличении "b" превышает 5 и условие (b++ < 5) становится ложным. Соответственно && уже не срабатывает и цикл завершается. Все это удобно проследить пошагово, немного изменив код и переместив вывод результатов на каждый шаг цикла.

```
public class Primer{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    while ((a++ < 10) && (b++ < 5)) {
        c++;
        System.out.println("c="+ c + ", a=" + a + ", b=" + b);
    }
    System.out.println("Конечный результат:");
    System.out.println("c="+ c + ", a=" + a + ", b=" + b);   
}
```

Вывод программы

c=1, a=1, b=1

c=2, a=2, b=2

c=3, a=3, b=3

c=4, a=4, b=4

c=5, a=5, b=5

Конечный результат:

c=5, a=6, b=6

Обратим внимание, что в итоге значения "a" и "b" равны 6, т.к. оператор инкремента ++  в обоих условиях сработал, но цикл завершился, поэтому "c" так и осталось равной 5.

Интересный результат получается при использовании в данном коде оператора || (логическое ИЛИ), который означает, что главное условие истинно, если хотя бы одно из булевых выражений истинно. Например:

```
public class Primer{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    while ((a++ < 10) || (b++ < 5)) {
        c++;
        System.out.println("c="+ c + ", a=" + a + ", b=" + b);
    }
    System.out.println("Конечный результат:");
    System.out.println("c="+ c + ", a=" + a + ", b=" + b);   
}
```

}
Вывод программы:

c=1, a=1, b=0

c=2, a=2, b=0

c=3, a=3, b=0

c=4, a=4, b=0

c=5, a=5, b=0

c=6, a=6, b=0

c=7, a=7, b=0

c=8, a=8, b=0

c=9, a=9, b=0

c=10, a=10, b=0

c=11, a=11, b=1

c=12, a=12, b=2

c=13, a=13, b=3

c=14, a=14, b=4

c=15, a=15, b=5

Конечный результат:

c=15, a=16, b=6

Здесь сначала работает булево выражение (a++ < 10) и пока оно истинно (true) этого достаточно для продолжения цикла, т.е. условие (b++ < 5) пока даже не "рассматривается" циклом, "b" в это время не увеличивается и равно нулю. Это, кстати, очень полезное свойство, т.к. если достаточно первой проверки не выполняется "лишняя" вторая, до неё даже дело не доходит, соответственно, не тратятся ресурсы. Затем при достижении "a" = 11 первое булево выражение становится ложным и начинает работать проверка (b++ < 5) и цикл продолжается - второе булево выражение позволяет это делать. Таким образом, по вышеуказанным причинам "a" достигает значения 16, "b" = 6, а "c" так и остается равным 15, до ее увеличения очередь не дошла.

Answer (score 1):

Оператор && подразумевает, что *оба* условия возвращают true. b++ < 5 просто перестает выполняться быстрее, вот цикл и прерывается. Скорее всего, ваша проблема связана с некорректным пониманием логических операторов. Опишите, чего вы хотели добиться в условии?